# Azure Ad B2C Authentication EmailMethod via Graph Api select

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to call multiple attributes via the graph api including the authentication email methods.
However when i try to select the authentication attribute, i always receive a null value.
Calling it directly works fine, however that way i need to call the graph api a second time to get all other attributes.

My Call looks something like this.

```
await _graphClient.Users[userId].Request()
        .Select($"displayName,authentication,otherMails,identities).GetAsync();
```

This way the authentication attributes just shows a null value,
even though the UserAuthenticationMethod.ReadWrite.All is set for the api

Using this works just fine

```
await _graphClient.Users[userId].Authentication
        .EmailMethods["3ddfcfc8-9383-446f-83cc-3ab9be4be18f"].Request().GetAsync();
```

however my goal would be to get it in one fell swoop, without the need for a second call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`authentication` is not a property but a relationship, so you can't specify `authentication` in `.Select(...)`.

Relationships can be specified in `.Expand(...)` like

```
await _graphClient.Users[userId].Request()
    .Select($"displayName,otherMails,identities")
    .Expand("authentication").GetAsync();
```

But according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#relationships) `authentication` doesn't support `$expand` and the endpoint `GET /users/{user_id}` [supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters) only `$select`.

So it's not possible to achieve your goal by one call